# Why dose Clickhouse performs slow when order by tuple?

Tags: clickhouse

### Table define

I use `clickhouse` to store logs, logs are imported into clickhouse as rows.
I have a table `tableA` with `PRIMARY KEY id ORDER BY (id, capture_time, offset)`, where `capture_time` is DateTime64(3) and `offset` is UInt64.

```
    CREATE TABLE dbA.tableA ON CLUSTER clusterA (
        `id` String,
        `offset` UInt64,
        `capture_time` DateTime64(3),
        `server_time` DateTime64(3),
        `indexed_tags` Map(String, String),
        `unindexed_tags` Map(String, String),
        `content` String
    ) ENGINE = HaMergeTree(
     '/clickhouse/clickhouse_common/dbA.tableA/{shard}',
        '{replica}'
    ) PARTITION BY toDate(capture_time) 
    PRIMARY KEY psm
    ORDER BY
        (id, capture_time, offset) 
    TTL toDate(capture_time) + INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    SETTINGS index_granularity = 4096
```

### Query case

My query case is `SELECT columnA from tableA where id = 'id_a' order by (capture_time, offset) desc limit 1000`.
But I found that query using `order by (capture_time, offset)`(takes 6 sec) is much slower than `order by capture_time` or `order by offset`(takes 1 sec), which confused me very much.

**Does anyone familiar with clickhouse tell me why this is? Or how can I speed up my query? Thanks in advance!**

### where id = ? order by (capture_time,offset):

1000 rows in set. Elapsed: 8.347 sec. Match materialized view: 0. Processed 1.21 million rows, 3.48 GB uncompressed bytes, 3.42 GB compressed bytes  (144.81 thousand rows/s, 416.90 MB/s, 409.47 MB/s.)

### where id = ? order by capture_time

1000 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.900 sec. Match materialized view: 0. Processed 1.21 million rows, 3.46 GB uncompressed bytes, 3.41 GB compressed bytes  (1.34 million rows/s, 3.84 GB/s, 3.79 GB/s.)

### where id = ? order by offset

1000 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.845 sec. Match materialized view: 0. Processed 1.21 million rows, 3.46 GB uncompressed bytes, 3.42 GB compressed bytes  (1.43 million rows/s, 4.10 GB/s, 4.05 GB/s.)

### order by (capture_time, offset) without where filter

1000 rows in set. Elapsed: 11.025 sec. Match materialized view: 0. Processed 1.65 million rows, 4.73 GB uncompressed bytes, 4.68 GB compressed bytes  (150.06 thousand rows/s, 428.86 MB/s, 424.30 MB/s.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be without `( )`

```sql
SELECT columnA from tableA 
where id = 'id_a' 
order by capture_time, offset 
desc limit 1000
```

Comment: I was finding information regarding differences when using parenthesis but didn't found any. @danny-crane do you have any link or reference to help document this? this is only for my curiosity to understand. Regarding the query, when removing parenthesis it should be modified to "order by capture_time desc, offset desc", right?

Comment: `( )` a constructor of the type - Tuple https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/tuple
In Clickhouse `a,b` <> `(a,b)`

Comment: Thank you very much! @danny-crane. I tried to use `order by capture_time, offset  desc`, it is really much faster. I would like to ask, because my query scenario is very simple, that is, `where id =? order by capture_time, offset desc`. Can I speed up the query by adding a suitable index? Or can the sort key for the table be `ORDER BY (id, capture_time, offset ) DESC` or some other way?

Comment: Clickhouse does not use secondary indexes for ORDER BY